# crawl sitemap with ABOT

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I try to crawl a sitemap with ABOT. I inspire my code from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/abot-web-crawler/sitemap%7Csort:relevance/abot-web-crawler/qM3A6nismno/A71P-TJyFQAJ).

after the crawl page is completed the text of content is empty ( `e.CrawledPage` in `Crawler_PageCrawlCompleted`). In addition, SiteMapFinder.GetLinks never touched.

please advice me where is my problem.

```
using Abot.Core;
using Abot.Crawler;
using Abot.Poco;
using CsQuery.ExtensionMethods;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebCrawler
{


public class SiteMapFinder : IHyperLinkParser
{
    private readonly HyperLinkParser _linkParser;
    public SiteMapFinder()
    {
        _linkParser = new AngleSharpHyperlinkParser();
    }

    IEnumerable<Uri> IHyperLinkParser.GetLinks(CrawledPage crawledPage)
    {
        if (crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.ContentType == "text/xml")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

        }



        return _linkParser.GetLinks(crawledPage);

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SiteMapFinder finder = new SiteMapFinder();
        PoliteWebCrawler crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler(null, null, null, null, null, finder, null, null, null);


        crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += Crawler_PageCrawlCompleted;
        CrawlResult result = crawler.Crawl(new Uri("http://www.example.com/sitemap/"));


    }

    private static void Crawler_PageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.CrawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.CrawledPage.HttpWebResponse.Headers.AllKeys.ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine($"{k}: {e.CrawledPage.HttpWebResponse.Headers[k]}"));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, my problem is on `app.config`. `text/XML` should be added for `downloadableContentTypes`.

```
<abot>
    <crawlBehavior
      ....
      ....
      downloadableContentTypes="text/html, text/plain, text/xml"
```

here is my completed code for loading XML and fetching the sitemap's links.

```
using Abot.Core;
using Abot.Crawler;
using Abot.Poco;
using CsQuery.ExtensionMethods;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebCrawler
{

    public class SiteMapFinder : IHyperLinkParser
    {
        private readonly HyperLinkParser _linkParser;
        public SiteMapFinder()
        {
            _linkParser = new AngleSharpHyperlinkParser();
        }

        IEnumerable<Uri> IHyperLinkParser.GetLinks(CrawledPage crawledPage)
        {
            if (crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.ContentType == "text/xml")
            {
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(crawledPage.Content.Text);

                if (xml.DocumentElement == null) return new Uri[] {};


                XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
                manager.AddNamespace("s", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);


                var links = xml.SelectNodes("/s:sitemapindex/s:sitemap", manager);
                if(links == null) return new Uri[] { };
                return links
                        .Cast<XmlNode>()
                        .Select(x => new Uri(x.InnerText));




            }



            return _linkParser.GetLinks(crawledPage);

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SiteMapFinder finder = new SiteMapFinder();
            PoliteWebCrawler crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler(null, null, null, null, null, finder, null, null, null);


            crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += Crawler_PageCrawlCompleted;
            CrawlResult result = crawler.Crawl(new Uri("http://tenders.rfpalertservices.com/sitemap/"));


        }

        private static void Crawler_PageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.CrawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            e.CrawledPage.HttpWebResponse.Headers.AllKeys.ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine($"{k}: {e.CrawledPage.HttpWebResponse.Headers[k]}"));
        }
    }
}
```